# Any recommendations for an smtp or email provider I could use for my Django project. I've tried several none work well with it

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, smtpclient

I have tried several email providers for my project but they don't seem to work so if you know or use anything not very common and it works well, I'd like to know as well and also I can't stress this point enough it must be free or have a free plan

I have tried the popular ones like mailjet,sendgrid,MailChimp,brevo,Gmail outlook and Yahoo didn't even work even after using less secure app settings in Gmail

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can try

- Mandrill
- Postmark
- MessageBird
- Amazon Simple Email Service ( I haven't try )